# Finding the Fourier Transform of Second Derivative of a Gaussian Signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am having issues trying to evaluate a particular Fourier transform. The signal of the Gaussian pulse is:

$$
u(t) = \frac{d^2 (e^{\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}}e^{j2\pi f_0 t})}{dt^2}
$$

Using the definition of the continuous F.T:

$$
\mathcal{F} [u(t)] = U(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{-i2\pi ft})u(t) dt
$$

I am sure that it is just a manipulation of F.T. pairs and properties. My first attempt at it was to assume that the end result would just have some parameters being multiplied by *U(f)* much like the property of derivatives of the F.T.:

$$
\mathcal{F} [\frac{d^2u(t)}{dt^2}] = -(2\pi f)^2U(f)
$$

I greatly appreciate the help or advice!

Comment: Your first attempt is largely correct. Is there something you think is wrong about it?

Comment: No I do not think that there was something wrong about it. I couldn't quite think of where to go from there after making that association.

Comment: $e^{-\pi t^2 }$ is its own Fourier transform so $U(f) =  \ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as you correctly stated,
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\right] = -(2\pi f)^2 \mathcal{F}[u(t)] = -(2\pi f)^2 \mathcal{F}\left[e^{-t^2/(2\sigma^2)}e^{2\pi if_0t}\right].
$$
The next step is to use the translation identity: $\mathcal{F}[e^{2\pi i f_0 t}u(t)](f) = \mathcal{F}[u(t)](f-f_0)$ to get
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\right] = -(2\pi f)^2\mathcal{F}\left[e^{-t^2/(2\sigma^2)}\right](f-f_0)
$$
Lastly, we check our handy [table of Fourier Transforms](http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf) to see that $\mathcal{F}[e^{-t^2/(2\sigma^2)}] = \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma e^{-(2\pi f\sigma)^2/2}$. So the result is
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\right] =-\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(2\pi f)^2 e^{-(2\pi (f-f_0)\sigma)^2/2}
$$
And here's [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%5BFourierTransform%5BD%5BExp%5B-t%5E2%2F(2s%5E2)%5DExp%5B2*Pi*I*f0*t%5D,%7Bt,2%7D%5D,t,f,FourierParameters-%3E%7B0,-2Pi%7D%5D,s%3E0%5D) confirming it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! For the most part I can follow along with the process, but I was wondering if you could elaborate a little? Primarily on the translation identity, so when you take the F.T. of that one it is essentially a frequency shift property that you must apply for the F.T. of the Gaussian that you did last. Am I understanding that correctly? That is why the final result has a (f  - _f0_) rather than just f in the exponential

Comment: Yes. The reason for the identity is that the complex exponential shifts the kernel of the Fourier transform: $\mathcal{F}[u(t)e^{2\pi if_0t}](f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty [u(t) e^{2\pi i f_0 t}]e^{-2\pi i f t} dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty [u(t)] e^{-2\pi i(f-f_0) t} dt = \mathcal{F}[u(t)](f-f_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important properties of Fourier Transform (F.T.) that you need to utilize here. One is the derivatives and other translation or frequency shift. I usually think that it is helpful to put Laplace Transform (L.T.) together with F.T. to better understand the rules or corollaries.

For example, the following minus "sign" might be even more understandable to be written as $(-j)^2$ or put in $(2\pi jf)^2$.
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\right] = \color{red}{-}(2\pi f)^2 \mathcal{F}[u(t)] = -(2\pi f)^2 \mathcal{F}\left[e^{-t^2/(2\sigma^2)}e^{2\pi if_0t}\right].
$$

To be general and also favorable in engineering applications, we also write $w=2\pi f$.
\begin{align}
\mathcal F\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)]&=(j\omega)^n F(\omega)\\
\frac{d^n}{d\omega^n}F(\omega)&=(-j)^n{\mathcal F}[t^n f(t)]\\
{\mathcal L}[ \frac{d^n}{dt^n}x(t)]&=s^n X(s)\\
\frac{d^n}{ds^n}X(s)&=(-1)^n{\mathcal L}[t^n x(t)]
\end{align}
We might recover the F.T. formulas from L.T. by replacing $s$ by $j\omega$.

The other step (shift) can be seen from [shift properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties).